# Use subprocess to run another tensorflow session

Tags: tensorflow, subprocess

If I have two separate models written in tensorflow. I wanna use output of the first model as the input to the second model. Supposing these two models are written in two separate scripts. Can I use subprocess package in the second script to run the first script to obtain the output?
Thank you!

Comment: You can use multiple graphs or you can draw these two models in one graph. It seems nonsense to use subprocess...